# eOriginal/eVault integration with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

My company recently signed up for partnership with DocuSign to build your
signing routine into our software.
The client looking to use our software currently uses DocuSign to sign
documents and has an integration with eOriginal as the eVault for the
documents.

Based on the documentation I'm reading, when the document is sent to
eOriginal, it is removed from DocuSign.
Is that correct? My client vaguely agreed that it wasn't on DocuSign but
I'd like to verify this.
We have our own document storage system as well and while we would like
eOriginal to have the authoritative copy of the document, we'd like a copy
of the document to be stored in our solution.
Our initial thought was that after the document was signed, we would
download a copy through your API and store it on our system.
We now wonder if that document would be there.
How soon after a document is signed would be it be pushed to eOriginal?
If there isn't enough guaranteed time to pull the document down, we'd need
to possibly pull it from eOriginal instead.
If we are pulling it from eOriginal, is there any information on how that
would be identified in eOriginal.
I'm not asking for their API. I get that we most likely need to get in
contact with them but is it identified by the same envelopeID?
Please let us know any insight you can provide on this.
We appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

**The Setup**

The configuration you're using all depends on your account settings. Please contact your DocuSign Account Manager to get a better explanation of the options and pricing here.

The most commonly used combination that I see with DocuSign/eOriginal is:

**DocuSign Transfers Authoritative Copy to eOriginal**

- eOriginal stores the Authoritative Copy
- DocuSign stores a copy

As far as timing goes, the event happens when the envelope has been fully completed. It could be anywhere from less than a second up to 15 minutes, depending on how DocuSign and eOrigional's queue's look. It's normally closer to the "instant" side. But I would plan for latency between the two systems.

**How eOriginal Stores Envelopes from DocuSign:**

- eOriginal uses `EmailSubject` of your Envelope for the *Containter ID*.
- There is an additional eOriginal Custom Field `Xref1` which contains your DocuSign `EnvelopeId`